# Repairing Win 7 on external USB drive

Tags: windows-7

Recently I put on my computer and it said it had to run disk check on my SSD,
so I let it,
it then found many "orphan" files and other stuff and changed it or deleted it or something (it kept scrolling really fast so I couldnt really make out) after which my computer wouldnt boot, it went right up to the windows logo and then it would restart and offer to let me run disk check again, i selected yes and then it gave me an option to go to "advanced" as it was unable to repair my comp... so I choose that.

Once there it offered to let me roll back to a previous saved points, I did that around 5 times but that too didnt work.

So I took out the SSD and put in my old HDD and thats working now.

Is there anyway to repair the Win7 installation on my SSD (I have put it in a external USB case so I can now access it as an external USB drive) ?

I have win7 on a separate USB stick that I tried to boot from to repair the SSD but I was getting the message "Bootmgr failed presss ctrl alt del to restart" (cant remember the exact message).

Please advise!

Comment: I'm guessing that you'll need to reinstall Windows on that drive.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid that... because I have loads of programs as well that I would need to reinstall :(

Comment: Curious how old the SSD is and model?

Comment: Kingston 256GB, around 3 months old...